# Class not found in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, classnotfoundexception, classnotfound

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactListActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

MainActivity.this is written in java and ContactListActivity is written in kotlin. I am trying to call the ContactListActivty but end up getting the error

```
 have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I have also added the activity in the manifest file.

```
 <activity android:name="Chat_Activity$Connections$ContactListActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity"/>
        </activity>
```

**EDIT:**

ContactListActivity.kt

```
class ContactListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver? = null
    private val TAG:String="ContactListActivity"

    //static variable
    object Obz{
        @JvmStatic val GetContactListFromServer:String="Contact List"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(layout.activity_contact_list)


        title = "Contact list"

        contact_list.hasFixedSize()
        contact_list.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this)

        getContactListAndNextActivity()
    }

    fun getContactListAndNextActivity(){

        contact_list.adapter= ContactListAdaptor(applicationContext, dbHelper(applicationContext).getContactList())

    }

}
```

Comment: How and where is `ContactListActivity` class declared?

Comment: It declared in the Manifest. @miensol

Comment: Could you show us the source code where you have `class  ContactListActivity`?

Comment: @miensol I have added the ContactListActivity class under edit section in question.

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest `name` entry looks suspect.

`android:name="Chat_Activity$Connections$ContactListActivity"`

I'm not sure what the fully qualified path name is, but try:

`android:name=".ContactListActivity"`

or

`android:name="<qualified.path.to>.ContactListActivity"`

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal what did you try? You need to be more specific.

Comment: Also, was the app compiling other Kotlin code before you added this Activity? Perhaps you haven't configured Kotlin correctly in your project yet?

Comment: I have tried your answer. i.e. replace the manifest class name android:name="Chat_Activity$Connections$ContactListActivity" to android:name=".ContactListActivity"

Comment: Did you try the 'fully qualified name' as well?

Comment: I have configured the kotlin in the same way as I have configured it in the other project

Comment: yes. Chat_Activity$Connections is the fully qualified name. right?

Comment: I don't know, you haven't provided your package structure. It shouldn't have a '$' in it, and I'm surprised to see an underscore as well.

Comment: Ok. This time I have removed the capital starting char and make it small in the package name. But got error `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'`. To remove this, I have tried the "Invalidate caches/Restart and clean options"

Comment: I have given the package name with starting the capital letters and given the _ in between the package name/folder.

Comment: Ok, sounds like you've solved your initial problem and now you have a new one. You should consider asking a new question and provide the relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, Try to rename Your activity add 1 symbol for ex: and inside your manifest
write

```
android:name=".ContactListActivity1"
```

after that you can rename again and set it old name